# ionic ion-icon no showing on android api version 24

Tags: android, ionic-framework, icons

I am trying to use the ion-icon component to display icons but when I run the application on an android emulator with api version 24, the icon is not showing.

Debugging the application with chrome: // inspects, the SVG tag appears showing that it makes a correct reference to the file, but the SVG does not render in the user interface.

[image]

Try it with a different api version and it works correctly.

api version 24 / api version 25
[image]

ionic v6.4.3
the project uses angular and is build with a capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code in ionic 5 with capacitor and it works,
make shure that your ionic menu has menuId="menu1" propertie and your ion-button-menu has the menu="menu1" propertie.

```
<ion-header translucent="true" mode="ios" class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button menu="first"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{titulo}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<!--Menu component in conponents/menu-->
<app-menu></app-menu>
<!--content of the page id="principal" here and no in router-link -->

<ion-content id="container" fullscreen="true">

  <!--Personal IOS header  NO CUSTOM-->
  <ion-header collapse="condense" class="ion-no-border">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">
        {{titulo}}
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
```